# Set Row security with Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, row

In my SQL database i have multiple users with different permission to update/delete data in certain tables. Is it possible to grant permission for user based on value in specific table column? Let me explain it better: Let's say user has permission to delete data from that table, but only if value of column in that row is true. If it's true it will allow him to delete that row. If it's false it won't let him.

Comment: CREATE a VIEW, LIKE
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE COLUMN IS TRUE.

Now give DELETE perfimssion IN this VIEW. Wont this WORK, I am NOT sure.

Comment: The problem is more complicated than that. I can't do with with only columns with true. It is used in many places in my application. Too many to change that view in them or do 2 separate views. I need to apply delete permission with condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is accesible by using the triggers on insert, on update and on delete. You need to have the table/tables with user permissions mapping and just before the changing value you need to check the permission.
But, do you really need this? If there is a lot of changes it will be a drama.. Another question is if do you really need to implement this scenario in the sql server. I think it will be better to check the permiission in the application layer - assuming that you have an app

Comment: My other idea was actually using triggers. So what i need to do is impossible on SQL layer? To grant permissions based on conditions in specific rows?

Comment: and ufortunatelly it is used in like 50-60 places with different scenarios, where people can delete that data and i want to add some permission level.

Comment: I have found this:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3030/implementing-sql-server-row-and-cell-level-security/
and this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2011/08/23/row-level-security-for-sql-server-2008.aspx
Please check if it match your scenario

Comment: I decided to do another tables and validate them by existing of index and not allowing to delete.